# Firebase deploy error : Can't allocate regions

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions

Trying to deploy i receive the following errors:

> Can't allocate regions or Segmentation fault 11 :
>
> firebase deploy --only functions node(15327,0x10eb6a5c0) malloc: can't
>   allocate region
>   *** mach_vm_map(size=6500430434105556992) failed (error code=3) node(15327,0x10eb6a5c0) malloc: *** set a breakpoint in
>   malloc_error_break to debug libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught
>   exception of type std::bad_alloc: std::bad_alloc Abort trap: 6

Answer (score 3):

I started to get this error on `firebase deploy` after updating NodeJS to the latest version. It was resolved by rolling node back to the LTS version, which you can do with `n` or any other node version manager, for example on Mac:

```
brew install n
n lts
```